get size of PNG from bytes
I am trying to extract the size of an PNG image from a datastream
Consider the starting data of the stream
137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10 0 0 0 13 73 72 68 82 0 0 2 84 0 0 3 74 8 2 0 0 0 195 81 71 33 0 0 0 ...
^                        ^        ^           ^                           ^            ^

which contains the following information

signature: 137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10
IHDR chunk of:

length 0 0 0 13
type   73 72 68 82
data   0 0 2 84 0 0 3 74 8 2 0 0 0
crc:   195 81 71 33


then a new chunk start.

The information about the size of the image are encoded in the 8 bytes of the data chunk:

width  0 0 2 84 or in bytes b'\x00\x00\x02T'
height 0 0 3 74 or in bytes b'\x00\x00\x03J'.

I know that the image has a width of 596 px and a height of 842 px but I cannot figure out how to compute the actual size of the image.
PS the values are given in Python and the here the datastream in binary form
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x02T\x00\x00\x03J\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\xc3QG!\x00\x00\x00\tpHY'

Use the struct library.

Thank you a lot!  struct.unpack('>I', width) solved the problem (I for unsigned integer, > for big-endian format)

Note that endianness is platform dependent, use  sys.byteorder to check the default. In my case is little

According to wikipedia the length is big-endian, not platform dependent.

You can think of each byte as a base-256 digit of the respective dimension. So 0 * 256^3 + 0 * 256^2 + 2 * 256 + 84 = 596, and 0 * 256^3 + 0 * 256^2 + 3 * 256 + 74 = 842.
The next two bytes are important as well, where 8 is the bit depth, and 2 is the color type. 8 means 8 bits per component, and 2 means three components per pixel: red, green, and blue.

I was confused by the choice of the basis, 256 = 2**8. Thanks
